# How can I map JSON to a .NET class

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, web

I want to map this JSON into a .NET class. How can I map this JSON data into a class? Please suggest how. Here is the json:

```
{"results": [
   "43853",
   "43855",
   "43856",
   "43857",
   {
     "questionType": 3,
     "choiceAnswers": [123]   
   }
 ]}
```

Comment: Please don't put JSON in your question title. It's really not needed, and not supposed to be here. Also, are you saying you need to create a corresponding model, or you need to know how to deserialize this? It might be tricky since strings and objects are different types in a single array in your example.

Comment: I need the model

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to `Edit > Paste Special > Paste Json As Classes`.

Comment: You can create Dtos based upon given JSON and use external libraries like Newtonsoft to map Json with Dto.

Comment: @CodeNotFound You can do that? Sweet.

Comment: On a side note: you probably want to look into the ContractResolver, since you are casting a Json string that has lower casing first letters to a C# class.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution is to use Visual Studio *Edit > Paste Special > Paste Json As Classes*.
But as your json is an array of different objects the .NET class will just be

```
public class JsonDto
{
    public List<object> Results { get; set; }
}
```

A list of objects will be painful to work with so I recommend that you to use a typed model but then you need to specify you need to define the values, here's an example

```
{"results": [
     {
       "key1":"43853",
       "key2":"43855",
       "key3":"43856",
       "key4":"43857",
       "question": {
         "questionType": 3,
         "choiceAnswers": [123]   
       }
     }
 ]};

 public class JsonDto
 {
    public List<ResultDto> Results { get; set; }
 }
 public class ResultDto
 {
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
    public string Key3 { get; set; }
    public string Key4 { get; set; }
    public QuestionDto Question { get; set; }
 }
 public class QuestionDto
 {
    public int QuestionType { get; set; }
    public List<int> ChoiceAnswers { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: But i dont need the key.i need only key values like "41254","45465".and the number of keys are not fixed it can have more values like key5,key6,key 7 as well.

Comment: @NazimAhmed Then you should use a list of strings instead, List<string> Keys { get; set; }

Comment: @ Marcus Hoglund But when i use list of string the keys property is receiving null values.I cant change the json but i have to map it to my class in exact format.

Comment: @NazimAhmed if you can't change the json model then you have to use the List<object> Results

Comment: @ Marcus Hoglund I cant use JObject becuase i cant install newtonsoft.json as my project is in vs2012.So it is not supported.I have to to parse this another way instead of List<object>.

Comment: @NazimAhmed JObject? You could just use object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use online converter to convert json data to c# models http://json2csharp.com For your json it would be something like this.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<object> results { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: my original query is how the object class will be.

Comment: Since you cannot have a fixed class as Marcus defined. For your scenario, list of object is the best option. Boxing and Unboxing will also come into the picture.