# Deserializing JSON with an unknown number of nested arrays representing a query

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, json, deserialization

I have some JSON as shown below.

```
{
  "queryEntry": [
    [
      {
        "type": "expression",
        "key": "Account.Name",
        "operators": "=",
        "value": "asd"
      }
    ],
    {
      "type": "conjunction",
      "value": "OR",
      "key": null,
      "operators": null
    },
    [
      {
        "type": "expression",
        "key": "Account.TotalEmployees",
        "operators": "=",
        "value": "123"
      },
      {
        "type": "conjunction",
        "value": "AND",
        "key": null,
        "operators": null
      },
      [
        {
          "type": "expression",
          "key": "Account.LastYearRevenue",
          "operators": "=",
          "value": "123"
        },
        {
          "type": "conjunction",
          "value": "OR",
          "key": null,
          "operators": null
        },
        [
          {
            "type": "expression",
            "key": "Account.Last5YearRevenue",
            "operators": "=",
            "value": "123"
          }
        ]
      ]
    ],
    {
      "type": "conjunction",
      "value": "AND",
      "key": null,
      "operators": null
    },
    [
      {
        "type": "expression",
        "key": "Account.OwnerName",
        "operators": "=",
        "value": "asd"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

This is actually a `where` condition in SQL which we are generating from jQuery. I have to deserialize this string to a class in C#.

Could anyone guide me as to what class I should create in order to deserialize this?  Also, it is unknown how deep the nested array goes.

Comment: similar requirement - check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386580/how-can-i-map-json-to-a-net-class

Comment: Hi Ankit, This works if there is a limit to the object. But the problem is that same object can repeat inside itself.

Comment: Yes, that is why list of objects will be a better option.

Comment: If you are going to query deserialized object, consider using Json.NET [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)

Comment: Hi Ankit, I will try that

Comment: Tried, I am getting the below error. 
**Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.**

Comment: Well, I am not getting exception with Json.NET v10.0.3: `var deserialized = JObject.Parse(json)`

Comment: Hi nrodic,

`JObject.Parse(json)` will not give error as it will be parsed a JObject. But I need that to be deserialized as a class or a list or array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a difficult JSON format to work with, because it is a recursive array structure where the arrays can contain either objects or arrays or a combination of both.  I can see that the JSON objects represent pieces of a query, but the query subexpressions are not within the objects like I would expect.  Rather, it seems like the arrays are being used as literal parenthesis for grouping the query!

I think the best way to get this to deserialize into a halfway sane class structure is to use the [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), where one class represents both a single piece of the query (i.e. expression or conjunction) and also a grouping of the same.  Something like this:

```
class QueryEntry
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Operators { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<QueryEntry> Group { get; private set; }
    public bool IsGroup { get { return Group.Count > 0; } }

    public QueryEntry()
    {
        Group = new List<QueryEntry>();
    }
}
```

We also need a wrapper class to handle the `queryEntry` property at the root of the JSON:

```
class RootObject
{
    public QueryEntry QueryEntry { get; set; }
}
```

Now, since the JSON could be an object or a heterogeneous array at any level, we can't just throw this class at Json.Net and expect it to deserialize properly out of the gate.  (You *are* using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) aren't you?  Your question did not say.)  We will need to use a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to translate the JSON structure into the composite class structure:

```
class QueryEntryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(QueryEntry);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        QueryEntry entry = new QueryEntry();
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            serializer.Populate(token.CreateReader(), entry);
        }
        else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            foreach (JToken child in token)
            {
                entry.Group.Add(child.ToObject<QueryEntry>(serializer));
            }
        }
        return entry;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To deserialize, we can pass an instance of the converter to `DeserializeObject<T>` like this:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json, new QueryEntryConverter());
```

Finally, if we want to convert the deserialized query expression tree into a readable string, we will need a recursive `ToString()` method on the `QueryEntry` class:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (IsGroup)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append('(');
            foreach (QueryEntry entry in Group)
            {
                sb.Append(entry.ToString());
            }
            sb.Append(')');
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        else if (Type == "expression")
        {
            return Key + ' ' + Operators + ' ' + Value;
        }
        else if (Type == "conjunction")
        {
            return ' ' + Value + ' ';
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Then we can do:

```
Console.WriteLine(root.QueryEntry.ToString());
```

With the JSON in your question, the output would be:

> ((Account.Name = asd) OR (Account.TotalEmployees = 123 AND (Account.LastYearRevenue = 123 OR (Account.Last5YearRevenue = 123))) AND (Account.OwnerName = asd))

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/D3eu5J

Comment: Thank u Brian. This is perfect. Yes I am using `Json.Net`

Comment: Could we instead inherit from JsonConverter<QueryEntry> in this case?

Comment: @TheBoxyBear Yes, you could.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/RX56nM

Answer (score -2):

you can covert using JsonConvert as follows

```
MyData tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json);
foreach (string typeStr in tmp.type[0])
{
    // Do something with typeStr
}
```

may be create the classs in the properties as fields if you want you use [jsonproperty] annotation for the class properties

```
class MyData
{
  @JsonProperty("t")
```

public string t;
        public bool a;

```
}
```

Comment: The object it self can be an array inside the array(nested arrays). How do we de-serialize that?